# how to change css when a scrollbar appears inside div

Tags: css, scrollbar, html

I have a question about the scrollbar that appears when it does not fit.
For example here I have one news item. Below a screenshot of the layout:
[image: layout without scrollbar]

And when you add more items the scrollbar will appear over the date.
[image: layout with scrollbar]

It's default behauviour for a scrollbar to appear inside a div, but is it possible to
apply css when the scrollbar appears inside. For example I could use a padding-right: 16px;
to the container. The only problem then, is another container is floated to it and these are inside a big container then the layout would collapse because of the extra padding.

Is there another way to keep the layout without breaking apart?

Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/EANbh/

and the css to the container:

```
.container {
width: 200px;
height:200px;
border: 1px solid grey;
overflow-y:auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
/*padding-right:16px;*/
}
```

Regards, Chris.

Comment: what exactly do you need can you post your desired result image....

Answer (score 1):

Another option without using the padding is:

```
.item {
display:inline-block;
width:184px;
height: auto;
border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but when you apply a fixed with for the item and when there is
no scrollbar then there is too much space on the right side.